# PetaPOCO: How to generate automatically class files for all of my databases?

Tags: c#, sql-server, templates, auto-generate, petapoco

i have 2 slq servers with many databases on each one. I've searched the documentation of PetaPoco but i can't find how to auto generate class files for each of the tables/databases on the servers.

Exist such a feature o i will have to go with custom solution?

In any case i only need a basic model of the DBs capable to start working... The overall schema is very big to do it manually.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Agree with P_G, also you can use T4 file if you want more control over the generated classes. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/t4/archive/2013/08/29/what-s-new-in-t4-for-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

> When right-clicking on a C# project, the following context menu functions are supported:
>   Reverse Engineer Code First - Generates POCO classes, derived DbContext and Code First mapping for an existing database.

You can grab the POCO's and ignore the rest.